# How can I react to quick successive taps in meteor on ios and desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, meteor

I am trying to make a button that increments a counter when you click the button however, it needs to be able to respond to fast taps. I have set the viewport scaling to none so that the fast taps don't just zoom in but even with fastclick.js it's still not registering every tap.

If I use the `touchend` event instead of click it responds appropriately but then I lose desktop taps and if I use `touchend` and `mouseup`/`click` then iOS responds to all the `touchend`s as well as the `mouseup`/`clicks` every few taps.

Any foolproof ways for responding to fast, successive taps in iOS and still working on desktop and other touch devices?

Comment: is it possible you just need to add https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/fastclick?

Comment: Hmm. Basically the same comment was made yesterday and I replied to it, but it looks like they both got deleted for some reason? I have fastclick and it's working, if you click once or multiple times slowly, it responds to the clicks right away without the typical iOS 300ms delay, which is what fastclick is for... However, the issue is that it doesn't respond to multiple clicks in quick succession without using touchend but then I don't get desktop support and if I use touchend and click/mouseup/mousedown/whatever I get multiple triggers on iOS for the same physical click.

Comment: it looks like you have a mixed code and there is an issue with it try to remove everything and hammer.js package (you can find it on atmosphere) it will handle touch + mouse click in one event handler so it will work for mobile + desktop with hopefully no issues

Comment: Hammer looks interesting. I'll try it out.

Comment: @MarkUretsky looks like I can make a custom tap event with hammer and set the interval very low, like 50ms or maybe even less. Will report back.